# How to dump tabular data from a webpage made of no-js class?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape through a web-page which uses **no-js** html class.
I've come up with code to scrape.

Now that webpage has a table always and I want that full table in an excel file.
That means scrape through the webpage and dump the table into a file.

How do I do that?

Here's the code so far.

```
var http = require("http");

function download(url, callback) {
  http.get(url, function(res) {
    var data = "";
    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
      data += chunk;
    });
    res.on("end", function() {
      callback(data);
    });
  }).on("error", function() {
    callback(null);
  });
}

var url = "http://kayak.com"

download(url, function(data) {
  if (data) {
    console.log(data);
  }
  else console.log("error");  
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the request module to get the page markup and then parse it with cherrio.

Cherrio provides a lightweight jquery implementation that can be used on the server:
https://github.com/MatthewMueller/cheerio

Request provides a simplified http client:
https://github.com/mikeal/request

```
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');

var url = 'http://kayak.com';

request(url, function(err, res, body){
  $ = cheerio.load(body);
  var $rows = $('table tr').toArray();

  $rows.map(function(row){
    var cells = $(row).find('td').toArray();

    console.log(cells.map(function(cell){
      return $(cell).text().trim();
    }).join(', '));

  });
});
```

Comment: You need to install the modules: `npm install cheerio request --save`

Comment: Um. this doesn't solve my problem.
I want the complete table with all its rwo-column entries. Using your code doesn't do that. I want the textual data alone; no html tags or stuff.

Comment: @R11G I updated my example to fully parse out the text of the cells.